# $1.44 million in holdings: Help my non-retired, 80-year-old dad invest it

Tags: portfolio, life-insurance, estate-planning, annuity, certificate-of-deposit

**tl;dr**    My 70'ish mother and 80-year-old, non-retired father have combined holdings of ~$1.44 million, haphazardly scattered over a number of instruments; help me *help them* design an intelligent strategy which grows their assets while providing a minimum income (note: their combined Soc Sec benefit per annum is ~$40k).

**Background**    My father is 80 years old, an immigrant from the Old Country, and still works four to five days a week. My goal here today: *educate myself enough about an investment strategy appropriate for our family which will bring him some measure of comfort and, ideally, relieve him of his belief that he "must keep working".*

**Investment history**     Being an Old Country immigrant, he's not been the most prudent with his investments: he's stubborn, financially naive & generally distrustful; and, unfortunately, despite the admonitions of his financial advisor at the time, he sold a majority of his assets during the 2008 recession, converting his moderate-risk portfolio (roughly 60:40 stocks-to-bonds) to an inappropriately conservative one (nearly 95 percent bonds).

I've developed a functional degree of financial literacy but by no means consider myself sophisticated. I have my own meager investments with robo-advisors that, given market's rallying since recession, have earned money-weighted returns of ~25 percent.<sup>1</sup>

I cringe thinking about returns missed by converting to a 95 percent bond portfolio.<sup>2,3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I expect this to regress to the historical mean for my particular allocation.

<sup>2</sup> I'm doing my best to make sure that this missed opportunity cost does not influence choice of portfolio allocation, i.e., behaving more aggressively on account of “missing out on the recovery.”

<sup>3</sup> Unfortunately, at the time, I myself was financially naive and wouldn't have known how to advise him anyway. No matter, the past is gone; *fortunately*, I found out about this “strategy” two years ago and advised we leave the major bank which oversaw his "actively managed" portfolio of bonds at 1 percent fees. (His investment "advisor" threw a fit when informed the SEP-IRA would be transferred to Vanguard.)

---

**Current holdings**    Since that time, I've essentially become the steward of our family's investments, which makes me somewhat nervous but which I know is better than the alternative. When I went through all his investment accounts, SEP-IRAs, CDs (`*slaps forehead*`), insurance policies & annuities, I was surprised to find he and my mother have a combined $1.4+ million in holdings (not including our childhood home, which is fully paid-off and perhaps can fetch $500k [the original price; purchased 1999]). In addition, they receive a combined Social Security benefit of ~$40,000 per annum.

Below are the holdings. Where possible, I've included return rates and any known fees (according to brief phone conversations with issuing company's representatives; i.e., *I have not reviewed actual contracts so I am almost certainly being duped to some extent*); also, I've grouped holdings by instrument type and then by descending order of rates of return:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    amount($)  | type [fees, %]                               | return(%)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       25,000  | life insurance policy #1 [?]                 | 3.0
       30,000  | life insurance policy #2 [?]                 | 2.0
       14,000  | life insurance policy #3 [?]                 | 1.5
       32,000  | life insurance policy #4 [?]                 | 0.5
       41,000  | life insurance policy #5 [?]                 | 0.0

      222,000  | annuity #1 [?]                               | 4.0
      115,000  | annuity #2 [?]                               | 4.0
       50,000  | annuity #3 [?]                               | 4.0
      410,000  | annuity #4 [?]                               | 3.0
       25,000  | annuity #5 [?]                               | 3.0

      197,000  | Vanguard SEP-IRA [0.30 + expense ratios]     | market
      115,000  | Betterment SEP-IRA [0.25 + expense ratios]   | market
       12,000  | Wealthfront SEP-IRA [expense ratios only]    | market

       25,000  | certif. of deposit                           | n/a
        6,000  | certif. of deposit                           | n/a

        2,000  | random penny stock                           | market

       64,000  | mom's IRA                                    | market
       23,000  | mom's nonretirement portfolio                | market
        5,000  | mom's annuity                                | 3.0
        2,000  | mom's certif. of deposit                     | n/a
        1,000  | mom's certif. of deposit                     | n/a
        5,000  | mom's certif. of deposit, SEP-IRA            | n/a
        6,000  | mom's certif. of deposit, IRA                | n/a
        1,000  | mom's certif. of deposit, IRA                | n/a
        5,000  | mom's brokerage                              | n/a    

     ?500,000  | home (mortgage fully paid)                   | market
```

**Questions**    The intentions of this post are many, but most important is to query the very thoughtful community that is StX$ to get a sense of “what I don’t know that I don’t know.” Here are the questions:

*High-level question*

- **Question 1**    Given the size of my parents’ holdings — and what seems to me, at least, to be a considerable Social Security benefit — can our family “afford” to be a little more growth-oriented<sup>3</sup> with respect to portfolio strategy?

*Life insurance questions*

- **Question 2**    The life insurance policies: I understand these least well; the current values are, to my understanding, the “surrender values”. If the listed values are indeed the “surrender values,” am I correct in understanding  that my father can recover, in full, the amount stated for each policy?
- **Question 3**    I’m not sure if life insurance policies are the most appropriate instrument for him to hold right now; my siblings and I are adults and I’m not sure our family would “need” the death benefit; also, it seems unusual to me that he can hold the policy until his death; from the company’s perspective, this seems, errr, not profitable. (Since, I would assume, each policy has a payout of several $100,000s.)

*Annuity questions*

- **Question 4**    Next, the annuities. The best of them return at four percent annually. He does not pay into any of them anymore; he is in the distribution phase for all of them. Perhaps it is better for the value in the annuities — the greatest proportion of his holdings — to earn at market rates? (In other words, is $822k too much money to sit in annuities?)

*Certificate of deposit questions*

- **Question 5**    My general belief is that these were all terrible decisions stemming from my father's inappropriate risk-aversion; he has continually "renewed" the CDs over the course of a decade; he does not fully appreciate the notion of inflation and purchasing power, so, it seems to me, he made little to no return on money he did not need to "protect for the short term." My inclination is to invest the cash value of the CDs as soon as they mature, so long as they do not create a taxable event.

**Conclusion**    In general, my inclination is to move the value my parents have in life insurance policies<sup>4</sup>, CDs, and annuities to a balanced-oriented portfolio<sup>5</sup>, somewhere in the range of 50:50 to 60:40 stocks-to-bonds. The rationale for this being that my parents will draw minimally from this hypothetical portfolio (given their SS benefits) and, in the very likely event of a market downturn, I am confident I can ensure he does not make the same unfortunate mistake of emotionally selling-off assets.

I would be indebted to this community for their thoughtfulness, critiques, and ideas. If you got all the way down here, I thank you massively for tolerating my longwindedness and ignorance.

---

<sup>4</sup> Again, I am least knowledgeable about what to do with these life insurance policies. Perhaps I first need to request and fully review the contracts.

<sup>5</sup> https://personal.vanguard.com/us/insights/saving-investing/model-portfolio-allocations

Comment: *"Help me design a strategy"* and asking for *"thoughfulness critiques and ideas"* are not questions that can be answered on a Q&A site.  ***Off-Topic.***

Comment: Have they _asked you_ for help?  Do _they_ think their investments are "haphazardly scattered"?

Comment: Welcome to the Money SE. Please take a few minutes to [complete the tour](http://money.stackexchange.com/tour). While thoroughly written out and full of pertinent details, this isn't the proper forum for it. Take your questions, break them down independently, and search this site for similar questions that already have answers. It's not possible for us to assist every specific scenario.

Comment: For #2 and #3 - life insurance should not be an investment. It should be to provide lost income that others depend on.  It does not sounds like they need life insurance at this point.  Whole life policies are typically terrible investments (from a return standpoint).

Comment: What you are asking for is not an answer to a question; you are asking for  professional-level advice.

Comment: The value on an annuity is a function of the projected future income.  Given your father's age of 80 years, his annuities will be worth significantly less than their purchase price.  I would guess they are worth a fraction of the original purchase price - perhaps 25% of the purchase price.  Thus, the present value of the $800,000 of annuities may in reality be worth a mere $200,000 if sold.

Comment: @DStanley yes, my father has indeed asked me for help; while I (and my dad) appreciate the inherent conflicts of a son being involved in investment decisions, my goal is to, at the least, minimize the percentage of fees he pays out to "investment advisors" (lesser of two evils, perhaps: son v. investment advisor?)

Comment: @DStanley thanks for your feedback regarding the whole life policies; I just don't understand why someone would have so many; is it unusual for someone to have 5 different whole life policies? again, he provides no rationale for them so my assumption is that he was convinced to buy "yet another policy" by a salesman who exploited his risk-aversion.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon somewhere in the process of composing this question, I realized I had passed some threshold -- that the situation is sufficiently complex that, "yeah, you know what, we need to find him a good professional advisor." That said, I had already written the damn thing (and sunk so much time into it), I figured I'd just put it out here.

Comment: @DaveyDiligence I don't mean to be dismissive of your concerns, but just pointing out that what you've brought here isn't well-suited to this site. Each of your 5 individual questions at the bottom of your post might form a good question in itself; where it becomes a problem is (a) having so many different questions at once [rather than 1 post at a time], and (b) asking for full analysis and integration of those answers into a packaged solution. You have done some good research it seems, and your individual final questions are well-formed; hopefully you repost some of them on their own!

Comment: @DaveyDiligence And if you do repost the question, consider rephrasing so instead of "Which insurance policy should I choose", something more like "Why would someone get x insurance over y?" asking for a "best-fit" is getting into the opinion side of things, and might also be off-topic, depending on how it's worded.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon no problem; thanks for the feedback; I'll definitely rephrase and post. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you do decide to rephrase the life insurance portion, try to find out if the life insurance is term or whole.  It sounds like whole, but let's not assume.  Also, how much would it pay, what is the surrender value (you may already have that), how much are they paying into it per month or whatever.

Comment: Your dad is 80, your mother is 10 years younger, the life insurance is for her not you and your siblings.  Your dad is an immigrant who has amassed $1.44mm of net assets and you’re describing him as *not* financially prudent; I’d say the opposite. Your parents are nearing the limit of their life expectancy and probably shouldn’t be in the market at all.  You can’t get in a time machine back to 2008 to change that decision, chasing it now while they have 10 fewer years to live isn’t wise.  Your dad wants to work because that’s his ethic, a bank balance won’t change that.

Answer (score 23):

This is not the answer you were hoping for.

I recommend that you stay out of it and let your parents do what they want with their money.

They are obviously very good savers and very thrifty with their money. At this point, they likely have more money than they need for the rest of their lives, even if it doesn't grow.

It sounds like your parents are the kind of people that would worry too much about investing in the stock market. If you invest them heavily in stocks, it *will* go down at some point, even if only temporarily.  There is no need to put your parents through that stress and anxiety.

At some point in the (hopefully distant) future, you will likely inherit a sizable sum. At that point, you can invest it in a more intelligent way.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Ben; you make some very valid points. Much appreciated.